# Matlab plotting, multiple plots with one script

Tags: matlab, graphing

Working on a review exercise from Van Loan's *Introduction to Scientific Computation*. It's P1.2.4 in case anyone wants to know. I can't figure out why my code produces a single plot.

```
x=linspace(0,2*pi, 30);
for k=1:5  
plot(x, sin(k*x));

end
```

It seems like I need to do

```
 plot(x, sin(x), x, sin(2*x), x, sin(3*x)....)
```

But this seems to be an excessive amount of hand coding, is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hold on` in a `for` loop. You also need to use the `'Color'` field in `plot` to make the plots of distinct color. At each iteration, just choose a triplet of random numbers between 0 to 1.

```
x=linspace(0,2*pi, 30);
for k=1:5  
    plot(x, sin(k*x),'Color',rand(1,3));hold on;
end
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want 5 separate plots? Then use something like

```
for k=1:5
figure
plot(x, sin(k*x));
end
```

Or all plots in one figure? In this case use "hold"

```
hold on
for k=1:5
plot(x, sin(k*x));
end
hold off
```

or the third method: use plot with X and Y as matrices